# regex for removing zeros in decimal string

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to remove zeros from decimal string
eg: 007.004(100.007) should be transformed to 7.4(100.7)

I tried using a matcher based on the pattern "0+(\d)":

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = null;
try {

    m = p.matcher(version);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Group : " + m.group());
        System.out.println("Group 1 : " + m.group(1));
        version = version.replaceFirst(m.group(), m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Version: " + version);
    }
```

but this results in 7.4(10.7). Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: What are your criteria for *which* zeroes to remove?  In particular, why are you supposed to keep the zeroes in the substring "100", but not the ones in "004" or either occurrence of "007"?  It can't be a strictly numeric basis, because `7.4 != 7.004` and `100.007 != 100.7`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a replacement with this pattern:

```
(\\([^)]+\\))|0+
```

and this replacement string

```
\\1
```

In other words, you need to capture all that is between parenthesis first and then looking for zeros. use the `replaceAll` method.

Comment: The pattern and replacement presented yield "17.141", not the "7.4(100.7)" specified by the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: happy that you reverse your downvote. The criterae of the question are indeed unclear to provide a correct answer.

Comment: It yields "7.4(100.007)" if the replacement string "$1" is used instead, which is what I suppose you meant, but that's still wrong.

Comment: I agree that the criteria are unclear, hence I asked about them, but a specific result is requested for the particular case presented.  This answer does not yield that result, even after correcting the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove *leading* zeroes before a nonzero digit, then you can match such runs with this pattern: `"(?<!\\d)0+(?=[1-9])"`.  That even uses a zero-length lookahead, as your tags suggest you might have wanted to do.  It would be simpler to use than yours, too, because it doesn't match anything you want to keep:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)0+(?=[1-9])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(version);;

version = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

If you're only going to do this once, then you can simplify to a one-liner:

```
version = version.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)0+(?=[1-9])", "");
```

Comment: I'm uncertain why this was downvoted, as it does exactly what it says it does, and in particular it performs the specific transformation given in the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I see a potential problem.  Presented with a string like `1003`, this will return `13`.  We know the result doesn't have to be mathematically correct (as you said in your comment, `100.007 != 100.7`), but I would get a ruling on this point.

Comment: That's a good catch, @AlanMoore.  Although I agree that we really need a clarification from User, I think it's most likely that he indeed wants to avoid stripping runs of zeroes between two nonzero digits.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to perform a replacement  in another string while matching another:

`while (m.find()) {`
`version = version.replaceFirst(m.group(), m.group(1));`

You can instead use this replacement:

```
version = version.replaceAll("(^|\\.)0+", "$1");
```

Comment: What about `(001.002)`?  I think the question is still not answerable, but good point about the API usage.  A `find()` loop that contains a call to `replaceAll()`, `replaceFirst()`, or even the non-regex `replace()` method, is not just redundant, it's incorrect.

Comment: @Alan OP seems to have walked away. Until then we will have no grasp of the real specifications, but to achieve what you asked for just replace `\\.` to `\\D`.